# logcheck ignores one of my ignore patterns

Tags: debian, regex, logging, logcheck

I use logcheck for more than a decade and never had an issue. Now some messages are ignored and I just can't wrap my head around why.

My `ignore.d.server/_self` contains:

```
^\w{3} [ :0-9]{11} [._[:alnum:]-]+ sudo\[[0-9]+\]: pam_unix\(sudo:session\): session (opened|closed) for user (root|logcheck)( by \(uid=0\))?$
```

However, I still keep getting emails multiple times a day containing:

```
Apr  6 19:41:09 radix sudo[4357]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Apr  6 19:41:09 radix sudo[4357]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

These should **not** appear. I am confident that my regex is fine -- you can see **they match**:

```
# echo 'Apr  6 19:41:09 radix sudo[4357]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)' | egrep '^\w{3} [ :0-9]{11} [._[:alnum:]-]+ sudo\[[0-9]+\]: pam_unix\(sudo:session\): session (opened|closed) for user (root|logcheck)( by \(uid=0\))?$'
Apr  6 19:41:09 radix sudo[4357]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
#
# echo 'Apr  6 19:41:09 radix sudo[4357]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root' | egrep '^\w{3} [ :0-9]{11} [._[:alnum:]-]+ sudo\[[0-9]+\]: pam_unix\(sudo:session\): session (opened|closed) for user (root|logcheck)( by \(uid=0\))?$'
Apr  6 19:41:09 radix sudo[4357]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
#
```

Why are these messages not filtered?

Comment: Absolutely nothing wrong with asking here, but you may find an answer more quickly in the future by using http://unix.stackexchange.com . You can search there now for an answer to this issue, but please don't double-post on both sites.

Comment: Are you sure the file is readable by the user logcheck? Despite using egrep, did you try your rules with logcheck-test? Are you sure, that you have configured logcheck to use the server rules? How do the lines before and after your pattern look like?